# sub domain hosted on another server but call it from Url Rewrite in iis 7 in domain

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have one portal like www.mywebsite.com and it has one module like booking. Current flow in url is that www.mywebsite.com/booking/. This is fine for current situation but we are moving to high volume traffic and want to divide it to multiple part with country and region wise and host booking module to multiple servers.

Now my question is that we can url rewrite in main website like,

www.mywebsite.com/us-ny-booking/ to booking-us-ny.mywebsite.com ( is hosted on different server ).

Is this working or not ?

Comment: Yes it can work. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I have tried it with this , <br/> <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.mywebsite.com/([0-9a-z]+)(.*)$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}.mywebsite.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>  <br/> But not Working it

Comment: Sorry For Not Formated!! I have tried more for it but not helpful for me

Comment: You want it to be the case only for `us-ny-booking` or do you have many sub-websites like this? If you have many of them, what rule do you need to apply?

Comment: I have one portal which has one module like booking, now by coding we are manage different stores but we are adding more stores and traffic will increase so that we are planning that region wise subdomain create so that multiple location hosting possible. so abc.mywebsite.com is on server001 and pqr.mywebsite.com is on server002 but my main application is on server001. so that if www.mywebsite.com/abc will open abc.mywebsite.com and if www.mywebsite.com/pqr will open pqr.mywebsite.com. That's it. But want url to be natural so that SEO can help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could go with something like:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="My redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(abc|pqr)/?(.*)?$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(abc|pqr)\.mywebsite\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:1}.mywebsite.com/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What it does:

- Checks that the url starts with `abc` or `pqr`
- Makes sure that the host isn't already starting with `abc` or `pqr`
- Redirects to `abc.mywebsite.com/whatever` or `pqr.mywebsite.com/whatever` depending on the original request

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine...!! Can we maintain URL as it is like in url www.mywebsite.com/abc but show content of abc.mywebsite.com. Because url will be natural and SEO will help

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of `type="Redirect"` you have to use `type="Rewrite"`. You might have to use [IIS Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to get it working.